# Firebase push notification routing flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the push notifications set up using firebase_messaging on my app. When the app is opened from a terminated state via a push notification, I navigate to a specific route (ProductPage) and upon pressing the back button, I get a black screen as there are no routes on the navigation stack

When I press the back button from the app bar or trigger the hardware back button on an Android device, how can I make the app navigate to the initial route instead of seeing a black screen?

I tried utilizing the `onWillPop` callback of the `WillPopScope` widget, but the callback exits the app entirely instead of navigating to the new route.

```
class ProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_ProductPageState createState() => _ProductPageState();
  
}

class _ProductPageState extends State<ProductPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context,"homePage");
      return false;
    },
    child: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Product Page"),),));
   }
  }
```

**onMessageOpenedApp callback:**

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
    print("ON MESSAGE OPENED");
    Navigator.pushNamed(context,"productsPage");
  });
```

The expected routing behaviour is close to this video below. Consider this navigation from quick action of the app, the settings app was not running in the background. I tap on a quick action, I get navigated to a specific screen, and upon a back button gesture or pressing the back button on the app bar, I get navigated to the home page of the app.

[Expected routing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WmwIsKZjtydNNsd-3Vikq-gyww566jyc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

you could try saving a backstack like here and adding it manually when the user enters via the push notification. 
Try debugging your app in this state. My guess is, that you don't have a full backstack opening the app via push notification.

Maybe this helps:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/multiple-back-stacks-b714d974f134

Comment: Like you said, the app does not have any routes on the navigation stack when it's opened via the push notification. How can I do this in flutter?

Comment: Ah, sry can't help you with flutter. In android java I would try saving the wanted backstack in a shared preference. Don't know, if this is the best way. Maybe this is strategy you can try out.